# Difference between jQuery autocomplete renderItem and renderItemData

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand the difference between `renderItem` and `renderItemData`.

I could not find relevant documentation about this.

I have following code:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this,
    currentCategory = "";
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
      if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
        ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
        currentCategory = item.category;
      }
      // with following code, when an element is selected
      // in menu list, the corresponding value appears in searchbox
      that._renderItemData( ul, item );
      // with following code, when an element is selected
      // in menu list, the corresponding value does NOT appear in searchbox
      // I override renderItem below
      **// that._renderItem( ul, item );**

    });
  }
});

function  handleSearchBox() {

  var data = [
    { label: "JAMES", category: "PEOPLE" },
  ];

  $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      str = JSON.stringify(ui)
      // with renderItemData, str = item in source data
      // with renderItem str = {}
      alert(str)
      var selectedObj = ui.item.label
      $("#search").val(selectedObj);
    }
  });
 $("#search").data("custom-catcomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            }; 

}
```

My objective is to custom style menu li items. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: `renderItem` is a method, `renderItemData` is an object. You shouldn't need to interact with `renderItemData`.

Comment: I added the explanation below, if you wanted to use only _renderItem then you need to set the data as `ui-autocomplete-item` not `item.autocomplete`

Comment: I think I got it working. I am trying to understand it more/better. I will accept the answer soon. thanks a lot. this helps

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`renderItem` builds the actual list item (`<li>`) that is to be appended to the result list

`renderItemData` is just a wrapper method that calls `renderItem` and stores the associated data (label and value) to the created element. This data is later used when navigating and selecting and option from the suggestion box.

You'll find that the source code for both is pretty simple:

```
_renderItemData: function( ul, item ) {
    return this._renderItem( ul, item ).data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item );
},

_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
        .appendTo( ul );
},
```

And you should note that `_renderMenu` actually calls on `_renderItemData`:

```
_renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this;
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        that._renderItemData( ul, item );
    });
},
```