# JQuery-UI gives "TypeError: n is undefined" and "ui.item is undefined"

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using autocomplete to get suggestions from multiple sources and show them as one list in the UI. When I am typing, the suggestions show up, but when I hover over a suggestion I get an error "TypeError: n is undefined". When I click a suggestion I get an error "ui.item is undefined".

The HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Autocomplete with Multiple Search Engines Suggestions</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this, currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    }
});

$(function(){ //page load
    $("#q").focus(); //set focus to search field
    $("#q").catcomplete({
        source:"suggest.php",
        minLength:2,
        delay:10,
        select: function(event, ui) { 
            window.location.assign(ui.item.searchUrl + ui.item.label);
            //document.getElementById("q").value = ui.item.label
            //$("#q").val(ui.item.value);
            //$("#searchform").submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .2em .2em;
    margin: .4em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #069;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #069;
}
li.ui-autocomplete-category {
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="searchform" name="form1" method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
        Search: 
        <input name="q" id="q" type="text" size="40" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP-script:

```
<?php
//Search term
$term = $_REQUEST['term'];
//Search Engine array
$searchEngines = array(
    "Google" => array("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&q=", "http://www.google.com/search?q="),
    //"Bing" => array("http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=", "http://www.bing.com/search?q="),
    //"Yahoo" => array("http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip?output=fxjson&command=", "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p="),
    "Wikipedia" => array("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=", "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search="),
    //"Ebay" => array("http://anywhere.ebay.com/services/suggest/?q=", "http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw="),
    "Amazon" => array("http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=", "http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=")

);

//Combine Search Results
$searchArray = array();
foreach($searchEngines as $engine => $urls){
    $url = $urls[0] . rawurlencode($term);
    try{
        //$json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json = get_url_contents($url);
        $array = json_decode($json);
        $array = $array[1]; //$array[1] contains result list
        if(count($array) > 0){
            $array = getFormattedArray($array, $engine, $urls[1]);
            $searchArray = array_merge($searchArray, $array );
        }
    } catch (Exception $e){ /* Skip the exception */ }
}

//Output JSON
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($searchArray); //Convert array to JSON object

//Format array to add category (search engine name)
function getFormattedArray($array, $engine, $searchUrl){
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($array as $a){
        $newArray[] = array('label' => $a, 'searchUrl' => $searchUrl, 'category' => $engine);
    }
    return $newArray;
}

//Read URL contents
function get_url_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $ip=rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/".rand(3,5).".".rand(0,3)." (Windows NT ".rand(3,5).".".rand(0,2)."; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/".rand(3,5).".0.1");
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example or sample of the output from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding this as a comment, not an answer, for the moment and I plan to update it as we get through the issue.

First, I was able to replicate your code and the error here: https://jsfiddle.net/xatu48sc/2/

I am using the regular (non minified) version. I encountered the error on Line 5836:

```
5826    item = ui.item.data( "ui-autocomplete-item" );
5827    if ( false !== this._trigger( "focus", event, { item: item } ) ) {
5828
5829        // use value to match what will end up in the input, if it was a key event
5830        if ( event.originalEvent && /^key/.test( event.originalEvent.type ) ) {
5831            this._value( item.value );
5832        }
5833    }
5834
5835    // Announce the value in the liveRegion
5836    label = ui.item.attr( "aria-label" ) || item.value;
5837    if ( label && $.trim( label ).length ) {
5838        this.liveRegion.children().hide();
5839        $( "<div>" ).text( label ).appendTo( this.liveRegion);
5840    }
```

The error I see is:

> TypeError: item is undefined      jquery-ui.js (line 5836, col 13)

This tells us that `item` is not defined, thus `item.value` is undefined, and so I included the code before where it's initiated. This will point us back to your custom widget to render categories.

When I compare that to the example at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories I can see a number of differences. There is no `_create` method and in the `_renderMenu` method, there is no `li` defined for items.

Somewhere in here is where the problem lies.

I have also found that this error is only thrown for items that have no category.

**UPDATE**

I found the issue in your code by using a Text Compare site. Here is the issue:

`self._renderItem( ul, item );`

The command in the example page is:

`li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );`

It's not using `_renderItem()`, but what appears to be an undocumented extension point: `_renderItemData()`

Base on this: [Difference between jQuery autocomplete renderItem and renderItemData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676667/difference-between-jquery-autocomplete-renderitem-and-renderitemdata) you are using the extension point correctly.

When I make this minor change to your code, it works without error:

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
    var self = this, currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
      var li;
      if (item.category != currentCategory) {
        ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
        currentCategory = item.category;
      }
      li = self._renderItemData(ul, item);
    });
  }
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xatu48sc/6/

I suspect there is a scope issue between the two. If this is not good and you really want to use `_renderItem()` then I can look into it. Using `_renderItemData()` does work.